# How to authorize DynamoDb using Cognito IdentityToken

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to figure out how set up credentials within my lambda (behind API gateway) using my idToken JWT which was sent to the server from Amplify Auth in my react client.

Is there a way to do this using an idToken and userpool?

In all the examples I can see they require an IdentityId or an IdentityPoolId which require the use of a Federated Identity.  Is this the only way?

Answer (score 0):

For API Gateway REST APIs you should configure a [Cognito Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html).

For HTTP APIs you should use the [JWT authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html).